# How to setup output path to compiled css files using 'vscode live sass compiler extension'

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code

I would like the compiled file in folder 'RWD/homework/css', not in 'RWD/css', how can I set?

This is my setup:

```
{
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats":[
        {
            "format": "expanded",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": "./css"
        }
    ],
    "[c]": {},
    "[bat]": {},
    "editor.fontSize": 16
}
```

[My target path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJciC.jpg)

Comment: Just change the `savePath` to `./homework/css`

Comment: Thanks! Is this only way? Should I change the savePath everytime when I createed a new folder? (e.g. RWD/homework and RWD/homework2, I have to chage the savePath when I compile scss in homework or homewrk2)

Comment: Well you can write the path relative to your sass files instead of the root with `~`. You can find the [extension documentation here](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/master/docs/settings.md) for more details.

Comment: @Arkellys It's a way to solved my problem, thanks!!
I changed the savePath to "~/../css"